# Xcode uses huge Ram memory (90gb)

Tags: xcode, memory, memory-leaks, ram

Has someone noticed the same problem? 
Currently installed version are macOS Catalina 10.15.1, Xcode Version 11.2 beta (11B41) .
While opening project - sometimes indexing takes to long, simulator does not launch, and all system slows down.
In activity monitor process swift appears and very fast - during couple of minutes it shows 73-90gb memory use, after which i have to restart, computer stops responding. 
I am having trouble with working in Xcode, any help is much appreciated. [image: screenshot]

Comment: What about the released version of Xcode 11.2 instead of the beta?

Comment: Unbelievable that this is still an issue 5 years later (macOS 14.4, Xcode 15.3). XCBBuildService taking 90 GB of memory, filling up and killing the ssd too (swap).